# Python MySQLdb executemany error

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am using the below code:

```
time = [[],[],[]]
for f,v in mydict.iteritems():
    fsplit = f.split('#')
    time[0].append(int(v))
    time[1].append(fsplit[0])
    time[2].append(fsplit[1])
cursor.executemany("Update MyDB Set timetaken = '%d' Where id = '%s' and source = '%s'",time)
```

I get the below error on execution:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

The list has values populated appropriately and if I iterate and use cursor.execute on individual items of the list it runs fine. Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Always* use `%s` as SQL parameter placeholders, and don't apply quoting yourself:

```
cursor.executemany("Update MyDB Set timetaken = %s Where id = %s and source = %s", time)
```

SQL parameter placeholders are *not* the same thing as Python string formatting placeholders; they happen to use similar syntax.

You also need to build up your items *per row*, not per column:

```
rows = []
for f, v in mydict.iteritems():
    id, source = f.split('#')
    rows.append((int(v), one, two))
```

or using a list comprehension:

```
rows = [[int(v)] + f.split('#') for f, v in mydict.iteritems()]
```

Comment: Have made the change. My timetaken is an integer field and so  am currently using this:cursor.executemany("Update MyDB Set timetaken = %d Where id = %s and source = %s",time). I still get the same error

Comment: @katrix: Let me emphasize some more: Use `%s`, **not** `%d`. The database adapter takes care of quoting and integers for you.

Comment: @Martijin Yeah. Get it now. It works perfectly. But, is that not a bad practise? I generally use cursor.execute with the appropriate parameter placeholders and have never faced an issue. Is this something specific to executemany?

Comment: @katrix: No; this applies to `.execute()` as well, provided you use SQL parameters and not string interpolation. `cursor.execute(sql, params)`, not `cursor.execute(sql % params)`. The latter *is* bad practice, it opens you up to SQL injection attacks.